# Return three largest values from distribution in one formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have the following datapoints. I would like to extract the cumulative percentage distribution of this set of the three largest values.
So first step would be to transform to 100% distribution and secondly summarise the three largest values of the new distribution.

| Data |
| --- |
| 0.00 |
| 1.35 |
| 11.05 |
| 24.85 |
| 37.85 |
| 15.40 |
| 6.95 |
| 1.65 |
| 0.25 |

I can calculate the individual percentage point with a simple `datapoint / sum of datapoints` per row and use `=LARGE 1,2,3` on the new column to sum up the values. However,  the challenge is to make all calculations in a single cell and just return just the final value.

In this case, the target value would be: 0.2494 + 0.3804 + 0.1548 = 0.7849 or 78.48%

Thanks for the help

Comment: Excel for Mac 16.55

Comment: The target value is closer to 78.61% if you don't round to 4 digits btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap a LARGE in SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(A2:A10,{1,2,3}))/SUM(A2:A10)
```

[image]

Comment: maybe my initial post wasn't clear enough but the division by the sum as pointed out by BigBen gave me the correct result. Thanks both for the quick assistance !